# How can i compare 2 items in sql that are in the same column in the same table?

Tags: sql

i have to produce a list with the following content:

For Example we have got an order with 3 Positions of the same Product, the same Quantity, etc
The only difference is the desired date of shipment of the customer. e.g the first position should be delievered on the first of january. The 2nd Position should be delievered on the first of April, and the third Position on the first of July.

Furthermore we can set a checkmark in our System that the customer cant split his Orders for various Reasons.

So i need to find out which Orders have the checkmark set to "NO SPLIT ORDER-SHIPMENTS" and still have gotten different shipment-dates for the positions.

I'm atm completely clueless how to tackle that Problem.

For Example Table A contains:

```
ordernumber|desired-date|orderposition|productid|quantitiy
123456789  | 01-01-2022 |     10      | 0815    |    100
123456798  | 01-04-2022 |     20      | 0815    |    100
123456789  | 01-07-2022 |     30      | 0815    |    100
123456789  | 04-02-2022 |     10      | 5152    |    66
```

In our System we have set an option that the sutomer of this order can no get split shipments. So we have an issue here. The order containst three different shipment-dates but the system wont allow that.

How can i find exactly those rows in that Table that have this Problem. I dont want to see row Number 4 of Table A only the first 3.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful .

Comment: Sample data and desired output will help us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will find the orders with different delivery dates for the same product with the same order id for the same customer.
The column names will need to be replaced with the column names in your database and may have to join 2 or more tables in the query to get all the information.

> ```
> create table tableA (ordernumber int, desired_date date, orderposition int, productid int, quantitiy int);
> insert into tableA values
> (123456789  , '2022-01-01' ,     10      , 0815    ,    100),
> (123456798  , '2022-04-01' ,     20      , 0815    ,    100),
> (123456789  , '2022-07-01' ,     30      , 0815    ,    100),
> (123456789  , '2022-02-04' ,     10      , 5152    ,    66 );
> ```

> ```
> select
>   count(distinct desired_date) number_lines, 
>   ordernumber,
>   productid
> from tableA
> group by
>   ordernumber,
>   productid
> having
>   count(distinct desired_date) > 1
> /*and
>    checkmark = "NO SPLIT ORDER-SHIPMENTS";*/
> ```
>
> ```
> number_lines | ordernumber | productid
> -----------: | ----------: | --------:
>            2 |   123456789 |       815
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf2d87e97b1eae912a39bd41973e17c4)*

Comment: So i tested Your Solution, it doenst work perfectly i get a lot of false rows. I'll edit my Question again maybe you got another Idea then. In your Solution i also see Row Number 4 of Table A.

Comment: I've coded it with your data and I'm getting the right data coming back. See modified answer. NB you haven't specified your RDBMS. I've run it on SQL server and mySQL with the same results.

Comment: Hi i tested around a bit on the weekend still not getting the result i need^^. We are using an informix DB. I'm not sure why the results arent the same. @Kendle

Comment: @kuy could you add some sample data to the dbfiddle and give me the new link, letting me know the difference between the output you are getting and what you are expecting/wanting/needing?

Comment: i got it figuered out. You're code was correct it was an error on my side. Thank you for your help.